# FME Writing metadata to ArcGIS Online

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, arcgis-online, oracle-dbms, metadata

I am trying to figure out how to write metadata to ArcGIS Online Feature Service from ORACLE SDE and how to update the existing Feature Service metadata,  using FME or other tools.

I am able to read metadata from SDE using the "geodb_metadata_string" format parameter when setting the feature read mode to "Metadata" on the reader, but not being able to write to ArcGIS Online.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What version of FME (+build) are you using? - FME Desktop/Server 2015.1 is due before 1st May 2015.. with lots of fixes.

Comment: This video might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9uHGX2hYqg

Comment: I can read, update, validate and write and XML Metadata file from / to ESRI GDB, but I need to write it to ArcGIS Online Feature Service and don't think this is possible.